# MongoDB equivalent to MySQL: select count(*) c, sum(if(x='A',1,0)) as a, sum(if(x='B',1,0)) as b

Tags: sql, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to write a MongoDB aggregate query that behaves like this SQL query:

```
select foo
      , count(*) c
      , sum(if(x='A',1,0)) as a
      , sum(if(x='B',1,0)) as b
 from bar
group by foo
order by c desc
```

I can do everything except the `sum(if())` parts

```
  { '$group' :
    {
      _id :
      {
        foo : '$foo',
      },
      count : { '$sum' : 1 },
    }
    { '$sort' : { count : -1 } },
}
```

What is the operator I am missing to do the conditional sums?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/index.html) is the operator you need:

```
{ '$group' :
    { _id : { foo : '$foo' },
    count : { '$sum' : 1 },
    a: { '$sum': { '$cond': [ { '$eq': [ '$x', 'a' ] }, 1, 0 ] } },
    b: { '$sum': { '$cond': [ { '$eq': [ '$x', 'b' ] }, 1, 0 ] } },
    }        
},
{ '$sort' : { count : -1 } },
```

Comment: My thanks! What about if you want 2+ conditions, e.g. `sum(if(x='a' and y='b',1,0))`

Comment: @DukeLeto just use `$and` with double `$eq` - you can basically put any condition there, it's not limited to single `$eq`